# Showing Progress Bar with jquery

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui

I am having a hard time getting the progress bar to show when the page loads. In this table, there is a list of names and points.  There are two buttons "plus" and "minus" which change the amount of points for each name. The progress bar is going to be linked with the points. So each time a user clicks "minus" or "plus" the progress bar will change.

```
      <tr id = {{ item.name }}>

            <td class = "name" >{{ item.name  }}</td>
            <td class = "points">{{ item.points }}</td>
            <td><button type="button" name="" value="" id = "minus" class="buttonminus">-</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="" value="" id = "plus" class="buttonplus">+</button></td>
            <td><div class = "bar_panel"><div id = {{ item.name }} class = "progressbar"></div></td></div>
      </tr>
```

I used the following to change the progress bar once the user clicks "plus" or "minus."

```
function vote(kind, name){
$.getJSON("/vote/", {pk: name, vote: kind },

function(json){

   ($(".points").filter('.hovered')).html(json);
   progress(json, name)

 });
 }
```

Is there a way to display the progress bar when the page has loaded without using JSON?
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: I made a nyan cat progress bar for jquery... can't remember where i put the code though :-(

Answer (score 0):

[QueryLoader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/) plugin may be useful. Check sample [here](http://gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/).

> What QueryLoader2 does is simply scanning the given elements for images (and background images) and preloading them before the website is visible.
>   This version has been modified to make it easier for users to implement (especially those who are already into jQuery.) QueryLoader currently works with jQuery v1.7.1 and in IE version > 7, Chrome, Safari and Firefox.